# Converting Pandas Column of dates to Days

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a panda table with a column called "date_of_work". This column contains date objects in the following format MM/DD/YYYY. For example 9/19/2016, or 12/5/2016

I'm trying to create a new column that assigns a day from a value between 1 and 365 so I can create a scatter plot with dates on the x axis. I created this function:

```
def converttoday(datex):
   datex=str(datex)
   newdate=datex.split('/')
   day1=int(newdate[0])*30
   day2=int(newdate[1])
   finaldate=day1+day2
   return finaldate
```

It ignores the year because I don't care about that (more focused on seasonality). Any idea how to convert this? I'm getting an error when attempting this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df['dayofyear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_work']).dayofyear
```

Comment: Hey @MaxU, thanks for your reply. it worked to turn it into a date time object. Once I do that, is there a command I can give to turn the date time object to the week of the year? I've tried this:

Comment: dt = datetime.date(2016,9,19) 
wk = dt.isocalendar()[1]
print wk

Comment: That produces the correct week but only when parameters are put in in that order. It doesn't show work with a date time object.